# hibernate does not work on fresh zorin os 12.1 installation

Tags: lvm, hibernate, disk-encryption, zorin

I just installed zorin os 12.1. I notice there is no hibernate option.

After some googling i still found no answer.

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

powers off the laptop, but after logging in no programs are running.

I also notice that it hasn't created a swap partition with default installation settings, can this be related? I'm not sure if Linux uses swap partition to hibernate.

Doesn't seem like hardware issue. I did it on 2 different laptops. one has ssd and uefi, other has hdd and bios.

the disk is encrypted and uses LVM.

EDIT:
hmmm turns out that i have this in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/zorin--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
```

I can't hibernate to swap file ?

Comment: From my trials, I cannot find a way to hibernate to swap file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You do need a swap partition for hibernation of Linux.

See the relevant AskUbuntu post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation) (should be similar steps).

Comment: I can outline the steps if you wish moderators - I am not able to comment yet though.

Comment: why the hell doesn't it creating one by default then? I just read that vanilla Ubuntu does that too. Is hibernate so uncommon?

Comment: more problems. The disc is encrypted and i can not resize the main partition in gparted.

Comment: Are you able to unencrypt? Creating is not default because it takes up your RAM space (Some desktops might have 64GB of RAM.....), and most people do not actually use Hibernate - it is disabled by default in windows, too.